# How to perform a click on a button on wearable and trigger another button on the handheld?

Tags: android, wear-os, android-button

I have an app on the mobile with 1 button. I would like to trigger this button via android wear. How can I do that?

The java code are still the standard created by the Android Studio and I will suppress them.

Wear xml Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="br.com.teste.wearbuttonclick.WearMainActivity"
    tools:deviceIds="wear"
    android:background="#5c6bc0"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/clock"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_box="all" />

    **<Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Click"
        android:background="#5c6bc0"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:id="@+id/wearbutton"
        />**


</android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout>
```

Mobile xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="br.com.teste.wearbuttonclick.MobileMainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Target Button"
        android:id="@+id/mobilebutton"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I suggest you read up on Wear development and how to send messages between a wear device and a connected phone, try your best accomplishing what you have in mind and then come back with some concrete coding questions. As it currently stands, you are asking folks to write your app for you. At a high level, you capture the click on your wear app, send a message to the connected phone app, capture that message on the phone side and trigger a click.

Comment: Ali Naddaf,
I'm not asking you to write the app for me. I already have a fully functional app. I need only implement this additional function in android wear. Your answer was vague. I hope others want to help me.
I have studied the android wear documentation and could not make it work.

Answer (score 0):

hello on click of werable app button send message and in handheld device onMessageReceived() call this method with your button name :-

```
private void makeClick() {
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    button.performClick();
}
```